# Exercise on $K[X]$-module $M$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

On my last worksheet I had to discuss the correspondence between a pair
$(M,\varphi)$ and the $K[X]$-module $M$.

Later in the task the following question occured:

---

Are there module isomorphisms $K[X]/(X^3)\cong K[X]/((X-1)^3)$ or $K[X]/(X^3)\cong K[X]/(X^4)$ or $K[X]/(X^4)\cong K[X]/(X^2)\oplus K[X]/(X^2)$?

---

And I really have no clue if my professor is talking about $K$-module $K[X]/(p)$, $K[X]$-module $K[X]/(p)$ or $K[X]/(p)$-module $M$.

Does maybe anyone has an idea what of the three would be the most reasonable for working with and trieng to answer

Comment: Most likely the question is about $K[X]$-modules.

Answer (score -2):

The map $\Phi(P)$ defined on $K[X]$ by $\Phi(P)(X)=P(X-1)$ induces an isomorphism between $K[X]/(X^3)$ and $K[X]/(X-1)^3$.

The dimension $K$-vector space $K[X]/(X^3)$ is $3$, and the dimension of $K[X]/(X^4)$ is $4$. They are not isomorphic.

$K[X]/(X^4)$ has an element of order $4$, $(X)^4=0$ where $(X)$ is the image of $X$ by the quotient map.

An element $u$ of $K[X]/(X^2)$ can be represented by $a+b(X)$, if $a=0$, $u^2=0$, if $a\neq 0$, $u^n\neq 0$ for every integer $n$. We deduce that $K[X]/(X^2)$ and $K[X]/(X^2)\oplus K[X]/(X^2)$ does not have element of order $4$, so it cannot be isomorphic to $K[X]/(X^4)$.

Comment: You are mixing the things even worse than the OP. At least they admit that don't know what structures to consider while your answer doesn't even mention that for the first and third example.